# ssl passthrough with BIG-IP connecting to kubernetes cluster

Tags: ssl, kubernetes

I'm absolutely new to BIG-IP, so I have some trouble about BIG-IP applying to kubernetes cluster.
I want our application to receive request on 443 port(https), and also BIG-IP to receive on the same. I don't want to (and not necessary to) decrypt, so I tried to configure my virtual server to ssl passthrough. I searched informations, and because the information I got said that all I have to do is to create virtual server without any ssl profiles, I create virtual server without ssl profile, but requests terminated BIG-IP. It's not seems to reach backyard application server.

Here is my virtual server configmap.

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-vs
  namespace: my-ns
  labels:
    f5type: virtual-server
data:
  schema: "f5schemadb://bigip-virtual-server_v0.1.7.json"
  data: |
    {
      "virtualServer": {
        "backend": {
          "servicePort": 443,
          "serviceName": "my-service",
          "healthMonitors": [{
            "interval": 5,
            "protocol": "http",
            "send": "GET /\r\n",
            "timeout": 16
          }]
        },
        "frontend": {
          "virtualAddress": {
            "port": 443,
            "bindAddr": "10.2.73.126"
          },
          "partition": "k8s",
          "balance": "round-robin",
          "mode": "http"
        }
      }
    }
```

If virtual server type is `Performance(L4)`, we can passthrough requests. But f5-bigip-ctlr is managing partition so changing virtual server type manually is in vain. Virtual server's scheme doesn't have `type`, so cannot configure through configmap. I'm exactly in the deadlock. Does anyone have an idea? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it! `virtualServer.frontend.mode` should be 'tcp' if I want to passthru ssl!
It was very hard due to lack of information about ssl passthrough, so I think BIG-IP should fix or add it.